# iOS Show effect bounce on scrolling up and down with white box how to remove this without disabling scroll ability

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, webview

The problem I am having is  that when you scroll up, you get a bounce effect at the top of the screen and which reveals the background and overlay.with white color

I have tried various solutions, including iNoBounce.js, Nonbounce.js and a few other suggestions I have found on SO.
Here Is Recorded Video Of Problem
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14vZEBiPn1BYxnpJtWq5nFd5wqJpU29ZF/view

**Website Build Using Glide No Code App**